# Chrome Remote Desktop to Ubuntu doesn't allow shifting terminal windows

Tags: ubuntu, window, remote-desktop, chrome-remote-desktop

I'm accessing my Ubuntu machine from Chrome Remote Desktop and it creates a virtual environment which is fine but you can't shift windows around like Terminal and Sublime Text. They all seem to stick in the top left corner, and any subsequent apps just appear on top of the existing window without being able to move it.

Thanks in advance! This is my first post!

Answer (score 9):

I'd lived with this problem for ages but I've finally figured out how to solve it. You go to /usr/share/applications/ and find Compiz. Double click on it and it will start a window manager (I think).

Anyway, the windows should move around now! :D

Comment: There is a bug when I play around the compiz, I can't type in the terminal anymore even I close and open a new one.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04:  sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager.  Then $ compiz &

Comment: I found out that following this configuration: https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#850359, I am able to access the Ubuntu computer without the virtual desktop mode.

Comment: the answer really resolved my problem thank you! ... although I found this method is still odd because I have to open the terminal all the time.